# css display block not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating show and hide on select. for refreshing the validator, I am removing the div class and again loading it. On first select, It works fine, but on 2nd select the validator not loading the css property. Only validator is loading without the css property :

My code :

```
  function getOtherQual(id)
     {

document.getElementById('other_div1').value = "";
var qualId = id;



if(qualId.localeCompare("Other")!=0)
    {

    $("#other_div1").hide();
    $("#other_div1").css("display","none");


    $("#other_div1").removeClass('has-error')

    var $feedback = this.$("#other_div1").find('.form-control-feedback')
    $feedback.removeClass('glyphicon-warning-sign').removeClass('glyphicon-remove')

    $("#other_div1").removeClass('has-success')

    var $feedback = this.$("#other_div1").find('.form-control-feedback')
    $feedback.removeClass('glyphicon-warning-sign').removeClass('glyphicon-ok') 
    $("#qualification_other").val("");

    }
else{

$("#other_div1").css("display","block");

$("#other_div1").show();
 }
}
```

Comment: you can done this by using display='none' or display='block' property  of javascript so why you use show() or hide() method.

Comment: Are you using jquery 3?

Comment: sjow and hide method is used for selecting that particular id only it will show, otherwise it will not show.